# fields(standard) Currency Field Bug

Tags: soql

We have installed our managed package in a **single-currency org**.  Our packaging org is also single-currency.  We are using the new fields(standard) construct in some of our SOQL.  But a very nasty error is occurring.  Salesforce is incorrectly including the CurrencyIsoCode field in what fields(standard) incorporates.  It should of course adjust the standard fields to the org it finds itself in.

Example query:

```
public static List<DriverLog__c> getDriverLogs(Id driverId, Date fromDate, Date toDate) {

    return [select      fields(standard), 
                        Active_Duration__c, Adverse_Driving_Exemption_Claimed__c, Available__c, Big_Day_Exemption_Claimed__c, Certification_Status__c, Certified_as_of__c,
                        Driver__c, Driving_Distance_Kilometers__c, Driving_Distance_Miles__c, Driving_Duration__c, End_Time__c, Off_Duty_Duration__c, On_Duty_Duration__c,
                        Personal_Conveyance_Distance_Kilometer__c, Personal_Conveyance_Distance_Miles__c, Personal_Conveyance_Duration__c, Remarks__c, Short_Haul_Exemption_Active__c,
                        Sleeper_Berth_Duration__c, Start_Time__c, Unavailable_Reason__c, Waiting_Time_Duration__c, Yard_Move_Distance_Kilometers__c, Yard_Move_Distance_Miles__c,
                        Yard_Move_Duration__c
            from        DriverLog__c
            where       Driver__c = :driverId
            and         Start_Time__c >= :fromDate
            and         Start_Time__c <= :toDate
            order by    Start_Time__c desc];
}
```

and the very nasty error:

```
No such column 'CurrencyIsoCode' on entity 'rtms__DriverLog__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.: System.QueryException: Class.rtms.DB.getDriverLogs: line 3943, column 1 Class.rtms.DispatchConsoleController.getDriverLogs: line 871, column 1
```

Has anyone else seen this?  Salesforce has not responded to my case as of yet.  Deer in headlights.

Thanks.